I need to caulk my bathtub, but a gap is too big! Solution?
I moved into a 5 year old home and found I didn't like the excessive application of caulk on my bathtub. I bought a bunch of removing tools and got started. Now, when I'm trying to re-caulk the tub, I encountered a problem I'm not sure how to deal with. theres a 6 inch stretch of area thats a bigger gap than the rest of the tubs line, I can practically fit my pinky inside. It looks like my caulk would roll down into a crevasse instead of sitting to seal. Is there a technique or tool or additive I can use to 'bridge the gap'?
Image below.
https://imgur.com/a/NrNfvNA

I have read on here about backing rods for large gaps.  Filling the tub up with water before caulking will help also, since it might drop down when full, but squeeze the caulking when empty.

There is not enough backer rod that you could put there to provide the proper support.
Mask off the area on the bathtub and tile with painter's tape. Apply expanding foam to bridge the gap. Allow the foam to cure.
Trim the foam so it is flush with the face of the tile. Remove the painter's tape.
Reapply the painter's tape around the perimeter of the bathtub on the tile and the tub so that there is a consistent line. Apply your sealant, tool and remove the tape immediately. Allow the sealant to cure.

I wonder if a little bit of spray foam could be shot behind there to provide a substrate for caulk.
